# Submit button name like an other input names within a form

Tags: php, forms, post, submit

I spent a hour scratchin my head with almost empty $_POST after submit form. There a simple datagrid, I select a row, js fills all inputs, button sends info to edit.php

Within the form each input (text/textarea/etc) has name like `publication[image]`, `publication[text]` and finally `type="submit"` with `name = "publication"`. Because publication is *current* table name, image and text - field names. *Current* table may be any.

With some table everything was fine. But some of them gave me `$_POST` only with submit button name and its `value = "Ok"`. By monkey method I found that if I changes submit button name to something like "updaterow" then `$_POST` filled exactly as expected for any table.

But what if I come across a table titled "updaterow", or such "useful_name_for_submit_button"?

And why I could not name button as other inputs has but without square brackets? And why when I did it $_POST didnt anything except show button name. I looked at http headers - they all went to the server properly.

Could I wrong with input names at all? Thanks advance.

Comment: always use `sumbit_[tablename]` as button name? for table publication: 'submit_publication', you just need to strip the `submit_` part and you know the table name

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with HTML or HTTP; this is how PHP handles PHP. You can't have two same keys into an associtavie array in PHP. If you do, the second one either replace the first one, or gets ignored.

In other words, you have to look at input names as PHP array keys (or 2D arrays, when you use square brackets).

Comment: I realized my mistake. Thanks mikiqex. Will name button tablename[0]. Hope such field name I will never meet.

Answer (score 0):

Change or delete your submit input's **name**

Answer (score 0):

For input type elements like text, textarea, etc you are using publication as array which will hold multiple values and for submit button it is not being used as array which will hold only one value. So $_POST values will return the values which is at the last in form.

If submit button is given at the top of text, textarea etc, $_POST values will return array values.

Try to use different name for submit button or else use the submit button name as publication[submit]

```
<form name="form_submit" method="post" action="">           
<input type="text" name="publication[title]" />
<input type="text" name="publication[text]" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="publication[submit]" />
</form>
```

which will return all the values in the form as Array ( [publication] => Array ( [title] => test [text] => test [submit] => Submit ) )

Comment: Goog idea but publication table may have field `submit`. I dont know what tables will be opened in the dagagrid. `publication` was just an example. It may be `submit` or like that.

Comment: You could just use name as publication[] for Submit button which will output the values as Array ( [publication] => Array ( [title] => test [text] => test [0] => Submit ) )